# Elo TouchSystems 2515 not working in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, touchscreen

My touch screen monitor in Samsung All in One PC is not working.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:219a Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e7:0124 Elo TouchSystems 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04d9:a058 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2232:1008 

xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elo TouchSystems Elo TouchSystems 2515 iTouch Plus USB Touchmonitor   id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elo TouchSystems Elo TouchSystems 2515 iTouch Plus USB Touchmonitor   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳   USB wireless KBD Mouse                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB wireless KBD Mouse                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SCB-1100N                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```